# After migrating pimcore 6.9 to 10.6 successfully, admin interface has router issue

Tags: mysql-8.0, pimcore, php-8.1, symfony5.4

After migrating pimcore 6.9 to 10.6 successfully, admin interface has router issue
[image]

I have changed routing as per symfony flex document, But getting this error

Also please help me to organize existing bundle after migrating to pimcore 10.6 version

which was there inside src/bundleName1/, src/bundleName2/ path, where to move it?

i had moved already src/AppBundle/ to src/ path, other bundles code can i make separate bundle folder and move it outside src/ path?

[image]